# Book with a fae prince who can only be seen by a teacher who lives in a small village

Tags: story-identification, books, audio-book

I'm looking for a book that I saw on tiktok months ago, I don't remember the title and the video that I saw has been deleted. The book has a blue or purple cover and it was most likely self published. I don't remember the plot but it was set in a small village (in England I believe) and the main character was a young woman who worked with children, she was a teacher I think and the plot had something to do with faeries, the protagonist could see them. The book was illustrated and I remember one drawing with the main character, some kids around her, a tree and a guy sitting on the tree e he was a fae probably. I remember searching the book on amazon and it was 17€ and apparently there was an upcoming sequel. If someone knows the title please tell me because I tried everything but it's like this book never existed.

Comment: What was the URL of the video that was deleted? Who posted it?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/48569731-bonded-by-fae-s-magic?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/42099677-my-crazy-hex-boyfriend?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/52850295-fae-king

Answer (score 2):

***[Between](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/55557417)*** (2020) by L.L. Starling is the book and the author is on TikTok.

> A bewitching cozy, fiendishly funny cautionary tale about the perils of gatecrashing fairy tale kingdoms—particularly ones with drunken unicorns, bored dragons, and sorcerers in tight, leather pants.
> Sasha Pierce hasn’t had a single dream since she was a child…
>
> ... until she accepts a substitute teaching position in the charmingly witchy village of Old Middleton. Her first dream in twenty-five years ought to be enchanting, but her wonder quickly turns to shock when she realizes that it’s not a dream at all, but an entirely different sort of magic. Catapulted into the fairy tale kingdom of Between through an ancient portal, Sasha’s astonishment is swiftly upgraded to panic when she accidentally performs a supposedly impossible feat and is declared the True Queen of Between … and betrothed to its infuriatingly handsome sorcerer-king.
>
> Lorn, Shadow King of Between, is desperate to break free from Between’s clutches. Magically tethered to the ramshackle kingdom, he wages a daily battle to save his disreputable subjects from rampaging magical creatures, sinkholes, and catastrophes of the distressingly lethal variety. To avoid an early grave, he needs an escape plan, not a wife...until he learns that this magicless mortal holds the key to his freedom.
>
> Unwilling to leave her world to accept the crown—or the husband—Sasha must race against the clock to disentangle herself from this fairy tale. But her empty throne leaves a dangerous rift between their worlds. As dark forces descend upon Old Middleton, the two must make a choice: work together or unleash fairytale chaos upon their realms.
>
> Between is the spellbinding first novel in The Chronicles of Between fantasy series. Filled with feisty, fairytale-savvy heroines, swoon-worthy sorcerers, slow burn romance, morose minotaurs, and bawdy witches it’s a laugh-out-loud fairy tale romp.